# Using IF statement on phpmyadmin SQL tab

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

In my installation of phpmyadmin, the SQL tab is not processing IF THEN statements. It does, however, properly handle the IF() function. For example, this works fine:

```
SET @thisyear = IF(YEAR(CURRENT_DATE) = 2018, 2018, 2019); 

SELECT @thisyear AS ThisYear, `foobar`.`id` AS ID ...
```

However, the following generates an error:

```
IF year(CURRENT_DATE) = '2018' THEN 
      SET @thisyear = '2018';
END IF;
    SELECT @thisyear AS ThisYear, `foobar`.`id` AS ID ...
```

This is the error message:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF year(CURRENT_DATE) = '2018' THEN 
  SET @thisyear = '2018'' at line 1
```

Is there a problem in my phpmyadmin config, or do I need to invoke something first before using an IF statement? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can only use if..then..end if in stored programs (procedure,functions,triggers,events)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IF` is a control flow statement that is only allowed in programming blocks -- stored procedures, functions, triggers, events.

`IF()` is a MySQL extension to the SQL language that is a scalar function that can be used wherever scalar functions are used.  That said, you can just use the standard `CASE` expression instead.

This distinction is actually called out explicitly in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/if.html):

> The IF statement for stored programs implements a basic conditional construct.
>
> **Note**
>
> There is also an IF() function, which differs from the IF statement described here. See Section 12.4, “Control Flow Functions”. The IF statement can have THEN, ELSE, and ELSEIF clauses, and it is terminated with END IF.